# org.w3c.dom Node appendChild(Node newChild) is not removing existing element

Tags: java, xml-parsing

In java xml file I am trying to add a element to connection node using appendchild. I wanted the existing server node to get replaced with the new value but it is not happening .

I see [in the documentation for this function](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild_org.w3c.dom.Node_) that the existing node will be removed.

win2k8

Comment: Could you show us your code? especially to how the nodes are created.

Comment: what did you tried so far? show your source code?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild_org.w3c.dom.Node_) says:

> Adds the node `newChild` to the end of the list of children of this node. **If the `newChild` is already in the tree, it is first removed.**

That does not mean, that the tag with the same name will be replaced. It means, the `Node` object will be first removed if it already is inside the parent, and it's about passing a reference to a `Node` that is already added to the parent, not about XML tags.

If you want to replace the existing XML element with your own, I suggest first finding (by iterating over the [`NodeList` returned form `getChildNodes()`](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes__)) and removing unwanted elements with [`removeChild(node)`](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#removeChild_org.w3c.dom.Node_).

Comment: ok. so I got to search for the same tag through all child nodes and then replace. Then duplicate check in appendChild would be of little use except for some exceptional case of adding the same node twice.